# iOS: iAd Singleton Confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I'm trying to handle my iAd via a singleton, since I'm using these banners in several view controllers. Now I'm confused of what do these objects store, since I move them around differently on each view controller when an ad is shown or if an error occured. Here my code:

Singleton:

```
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static MySingleton * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {

            self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
        } else {
            self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here how it is initalized:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //iAd
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kInAppPurchaseNoAds]){
        self.bannerView = [MySingleton sharedInstance].bannerView;
        self.bannerView.delegate = self;
        self.bannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bannerView.frame, 0, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
    }
}
```

And the delegate methods:

```
- (void)showBanner
{
    if(!self.isBannerVisible){
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             //Restore the constraint
                             self.mainContainerToSuperviewConstraint.constant = 50;
                             //Move the banner on
                             self.bannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bannerView.frame, 0, -50);
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             self.isBannerVisible = YES;
                         }];
    }
}

- (void)hideBanner
{
    if(self.isBannerVisible){
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             //Restore the constraint
                             self.mainContainerToSuperviewConstraint.constant = 0;
                             //Move the banner off
                             self.bannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bannerView.frame, 0, self.bannerView.frame.size.height);
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             self.isBannerVisible = NO;
                         }];
    }
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self showBanner];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self hideBanner];
}
```

Now what I'm confused is, do I have to check the position of the banner view again if the user was in another view with also an iAd where the rectangle with visible banner was at let's say 75 from the bottom of the screen and not 50? Or do these positions do not influence the AdBannerView but only the single object in each class?! I mean if he was in the other view and there the code moved the Banner to 75 pixels from the bottom, are these 75 pixels stored in my singleton AdView? So the original view had the banner now at 75 and not at 50?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest against having a singleton for a view - one view instance can be a subview only of 1 view, so you need to track adding/removing it and also you need to set the frame every time you add it again as a subview. You better have some kind of base view controller to share the instantiation logic and the control of the banners.

Comment: But isn't it recommended to create the iAd BannerView as a Singleton? I mean I have 3 view controllers showing an iAd, I can instantiate everytime a new one without problems.